# How do I keep a deployed NodeJS web app on Heroku from exiting before receiving POST data?

Tags: node.js, http, post, heroku, web-applications

I'm very inexperienced in server-based apps (and only slightly more experienced in client-side apps). However, based on a number of examples (mostly here on Stack Overflow), I have created a basic NodeJS web app, which works correctly when run locally (e.g. "heroku local web"). But when deployed the app doesn't receive POSTed data, unless I insert a delay. I'm certain that I'm doing something wrong, so I'm hoping someone can point me at the correct way to handle this. I've distilled the app down to the basic issue, which still shows up using the code below.

Basically, as I understand it, the simple web page posts JSON data to my web app. The web app does receive the POST message. But before the web app can collect the data being transferred, the web app appears to exit. The data is not lost when the app is run locally (and it was not lost when I had deployed an early version on Google Cloud). But the loss does occur when deployed on Heroku (free tier).

Experience in several other languages leaves me confused as to why the NodeJS app doesn't always exit before receiving any messages, since no code is in the app to delay the exit (e.g. a message pump or wait for an exit signal). When it worked, I just shrugged and decided there was some magic in play that I would learn about later. But in reality, the failure I'm seeing makes more sense to me.

In any case, it was this doubt that led me to add the delay (added lines shown below with comments of //***). From that I was able to determine that the data was arriving, but not being collected, without the delay.

Below are the main code files. Under those are some logs showing local & remote behavior before and after the delay was added.

Any help appreciated.

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html lang='en'>
<meta http-equiv='Content-Language' content='en'>
<head>
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=UTF-8'>

<script>

var scriptlocation = location.href.replace(document.location.pathname, '');
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

function OnReadyStateChange() {
  if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
    console.log("Data upload complete.");
  }
}

function SendDataToServer(data) {
  var url = scriptlocation + "/server.js";
  request.open('POST', url, true);
  request.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
  request.onreadystatechange = OnReadyStateChange;
  request.send(data);
}

function SendEntryDataToServer() {
  var entryData = {
    fruit: "apple",
    size: "medium",
    color: "red"
  };
  console.log("*** SENDING DATA TO SERVER ***");
  var postData = JSON.stringify(entryData);
  SendDataToServer(postData);
  return false;
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
  <form>
    <input type="button" onclick="SendEntryDataToServer()" value="Post Data"/>
  </form>
</body>
```

server.js:

```
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');

var server = http.createServer(
  function (req, res) {
    console.log(`req.url: ${req.url}\n`);

    if (req.method == 'POST') {
      console.log("POST");

      var body = '';

      req.on('data', function (data) {
        body += data;
      });

      req.on('end', function (data) {
        console.log(JSON.parse(body));
      });

      res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
      res.end('post received');

      console.log("Sleeping 5 seconds"); // ***
      setTimeout(function(){             // ***
        console.log("POST end");
      }, 5000);                          // ***
    } else {
      console.log("GET");

      fs.readFile('./' + req.url, function(err, data) {
        if (!err) {
          var dotoffset = req.url.lastIndexOf('.');
          var mimetype = dotoffset == -1
                        ? 'text/plain'
                        : {
                          '.html' : 'text/html',
                          '.ico' : 'image/x-icon',
                          '.jpg' : 'image/jpeg',
                          '.png' : 'image/png',
                          '.gif' : 'image/gif',
                          '.css' : 'text/css',
                          '.js' : 'text/javascript'
                        }[ req.url.substr(dotoffset) ];
          res.setHeader('Content-type' , mimetype);
          res.end(data);
        } else {
          console.log ('file not found: ' + req.url);
          res.writeHead(404, "Not Found");
          res.end();
        }
      });
    }
  }
);

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
server.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running (port: ${PORT})...`);
});

console.log("FILE end");
```

Local before delay added:

```
10:24:00 PM web.1 |  FILE end
10:24:00 PM web.1 |  Server is running (port: 5000)...
10:24:14 PM web.1 |  req.url: /index.html
10:24:14 PM web.1 |  GET
10:24:18 PM web.1 |  req.url: /server.js
10:24:18 PM web.1 |  POST
10:24:18 PM web.1 |  POST end
10:24:18 PM web.1 |  { fruit: 'apple', size: 'medium', color: 'red' }
```

Deployed before delay added:

```
2019-12-18T04:31:52.835329+00:00 app[web.1]: FILE end
2019-12-18T04:31:52.837439+00:00 app[web.1]: Server is running (port: 17378)...
2019-12-18T04:32:14.929250+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/index.html" host=****.herokuapp.com request_id=**** fwd="*.*.*.*" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=9ms status=200 bytes=1233 protocol=https
2019-12-18T04:32:14.925381+00:00 app[web.1]: req.url: /index.html
2019-12-18T04:32:14.925407+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-12-18T04:32:14.925509+00:00 app[web.1]: GET
2019-12-18T04:32:25.004774+00:00 app[web.1]: req.url: /server.js
2019-12-18T04:32:25.004809+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-12-18T04:32:25.004964+00:00 app[web.1]: POST
2019-12-18T04:32:25.006023+00:00 app[web.1]: POST end
```

Local after delay added:

```
10:48:04 PM web.1 |  FILE end
10:48:04 PM web.1 |  Server is running (port: 5000)...
10:48:08 PM web.1 |  req.url: /index.html
10:48:08 PM web.1 |  GET
10:48:12 PM web.1 |  req.url: /server.js
10:48:12 PM web.1 |  POST
10:48:12 PM web.1 |  Sleeping 5 seconds
10:48:12 PM web.1 |  { fruit: 'apple', size: 'medium', color: 'red' }
10:48:17 PM web.1 |  POST end
```

Deployed after delay added:

```
2019-12-18T04:51:50.925802+00:00 app[web.1]: req.url: /index.html
2019-12-18T04:51:50.925831+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-12-18T04:51:50.925944+00:00 app[web.1]: GET
2019-12-18T04:51:56.071684+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/server.js" host=****.herokuapp.com request_id=**** fwd="*.*.*.*" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=6ms status=200 bytes=151 protocol=https
2019-12-18T04:51:56.064644+00:00 app[web.1]: req.url: /server.js
2019-12-18T04:51:56.064659+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-12-18T04:51:56.068033+00:00 app[web.1]: POST
2019-12-18T04:51:56.069013+00:00 app[web.1]: Sleeping 5 seconds
2019-12-18T04:51:56.075197+00:00 app[web.1]: { fruit: 'apple', size: 'medium', color: 'red' }
2019-12-18T04:52:01.073243+00:00 app[web.1]: POST end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone runs across this later, I didn't get any feedback on this, and could not really find a reasonable workaround. (I tried promises and some other ad-hoc signalling.) So I side-stepped this by using Express as my server, knowing that this is successfully deployed worldwide. Switching was trivial, given the extremely simple data transfer, and it works fine. (I intended to dig into the Express source to see how they handled it, but it seems that including it in my NodeJS app imported something over 200 other packages, so that was quite a discouragement to dig around.)